# Como criar uma árvore de categorias em C#

Tags: c#, algoritmo

### Base de dados

Tenho uma base de dados com códigos de produtos e serviços (para concursos público) e queria arranjar uma maneira de criar uma "árvore" para esses códigos. Vejam como tenho configurada a minha base de dados na seguinte imagem:

[image: Screenshot do 'Design Table']

### Objetivo

O `ParentID` é a coluna onde se guarda o pai do código, ou seja, cada pai que existir vai ter de ter uma expansão para mostrar os filhos. Veja um exemplo do que quero obter na seguinte imagem:

[image: Árvore final que quero obter]

### Observações

- O que fica no `ParentID` do filho é o `CPCID` do pai.
- Na raíz existem 9 pais
- A base de dados tem 32k+ linhas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já passei pela mesma situação e resolvi usando `Linq` da seguinte forma:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace XXX
{
    public class TreeviewItem
    {
        public TreeviewItem()
        {
            Children = new List<TreeviewItem>();
        }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public int? ValuePai { get; set; }
        public bool Checked { get; set; }
        public bool Disabled { get; set; }
        public bool Collapsed { get; set; }
        public List<TreeviewItem> Children { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Métodos:

```
    public List<TreeviewItem> ObterListaAninhada(List<TreeviewItem> lstFuncoes)
    {
        var lstFuncoesAninhadas = lstFuncoes.Where(x => x.ValuePai == 0)
                                            .Select(x => new TreeviewItem
                                            {
                                                Value = x.Value,
                                                ValuePai = x.ValuePai,
                                                Text = x.Text,
                                                Checked = x.Checked,
                                                Collapsed = x.Collapsed,
                                                Disabled = x.Disabled,
                                                Children = ObterFuncoesFilhas(lstFuncoes, x.Value)
                                            }).ToList();
        return lstFuncoesAninhadas;
    }

    private List<TreeviewItem> ObterFuncoesFilhas(List<TreeviewItem> lstFunction, int id)
    {

        return lstFunction.Where(x => x.ValuePai == id)
                          .Select(x => new TreeviewItem
                          {
                              Value = x.Value,
                              ValuePai = x.ValuePai,
                              Text = x.Text,
                              Checked = x.Checked,
                              Collapsed = x.Collapsed,
                              Disabled = x.Disabled,
                              Children = ObterFuncoesFilhas(lstFunction, x.Value)
                          }).ToList();
    }
```

Exemplo simples do resultado em Json:

```
{
    "text": "Teste",
    "value": 305,
    "valuePai": 0,
    "checked": false,
    "disabled": true,
    "collapsed": true,
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "Teste.pdf",
        "value": 483,
        "valuePai": 305,
        "checked": false,
        "disabled": false,
        "collapsed": true,
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "text": "Teste.txt",
        "value": 487,
        "valuePai": 305,
        "checked": false,
        "disabled": false,
        "collapsed": true,
        "children": []
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi direto sua pergunta, mas veja se o código a seguir te ajudar em algo:

```
using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ArvoreDeCategoria
 {
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            Categoria categoriaRaiz = new Categoria();

            Categoria categoria1 = new Categoria();
            categoria1.Code = "Code 1";
            categoria1.CPCID = 1;
            categoria1.NumLevel = 1;
            categoria1.ParentID = null;
            categoria1.PT = "Categoria 1";
            categoria1.EN = "Category 1 ";

            Categoria categoria2 = new Categoria();
            categoria2.Code = "Code 2";
            categoria2.CPCID = 2;
            categoria2.NumLevel = 2;
            categoria2.ParentID = null;
            categoria2.PT = "Categoria 2";
            categoria2.EN = "Category 2 ";

            Categoria subcategoria1 = new Categoria();
            subcategoria1.Code = "Code Sub 1";
            subcategoria1.CPCID = 3;
            subcategoria1.NumLevel = 1;
            subcategoria1.ParentID = 1;
            subcategoria1.PT = "Sub-Categoria 1";
            subcategoria1.EN = "Sub-Category 1 ";

            Categoria subsubcategoria1 = new Categoria();
            subsubcategoria1.Code = "Code Sub Sub 1";
            subsubcategoria1.CPCID = 4;
            subsubcategoria1.NumLevel = 1;
            subsubcategoria1.ParentID = 1;
            subsubcategoria1.PT = "Sub-Sub-Categoria 1";
            subsubcategoria1.EN = "Sub-Sub-Category 1 ";

            subcategoria1.Add(subsubcategoria1);

            categoria1.Add(subcategoria1);

            categoriaRaiz.Add(categoria1);
            categoriaRaiz.Add(categoria2);

            categoriaRaiz.Display(1);

         }
    }

    public class Categoria
    {
        public int NumLevel { get; set; }
        public int CPCID { get; set; }
        public int? ParentID { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string PT { get; set; }
        public string EN { get; set; }
        public string ES { get; set; }
        public string IT { get; set; }

        private readonly ICollection<Categoria> subcategorias;

        public Categoria()
        {
            subcategorias = new List<Categoria>();
        }

        public void Add(Categoria categoria)
        {
            subcategorias.Add(categoria);
        }

        public void Display(int depth)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new String('-', depth) + PT);

            foreach (Categoria categoria in subcategorias)
            {
                categoria.Display(depth + 2);
            }
        }

        public void Remove(Categoria categoria)
        {
            subcategorias.Remove(categoria);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o segredo aqui está mais na consulta ao BD do que no C# propriamente. No SQL SERVER (que parece ser o caso) eu vou com uma CTE. Aqui vai um exemplo somente escrevendo a saída hierarquicamente, mas eu faria um componente a parte para links, rotas e outras especificidades que sejam necessárias.

A classe Categoria

```
public class Categoria
{
    public Categoria()
    {

    }

    public int NumLevel { get; set; }

    public int CPCID { get; set; }

    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    public String Code { get; set; }

    public String Nodes { get; set; }

    public String EN { get; set; }

    public String PT { get; set; }

    public String ES { get; set; }

    public String IT { get; set; }

    public List<Categoria> CategoriasFilho { get; set; }
}
```

O método do Main do Console

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Executamos a CTE
        SqlConnection Conn = DAL.Conexao.AbreConexaoApoio();

        StringBuilder cmdText = new StringBuilder();

        cmdText.Append(";WITH ArvoreCategorias AS ( ");
        cmdText.Append("    SELECT NumLevel, CPCID, ParentID, Code, PT, EN, ES, IT, 1 as Level, CAST(Code as varchar(max)) as Nodes FROM Categorias WHERE ParentID = 0");
        cmdText.Append("    UNION ALL");
        cmdText.Append("    SELECT c.NumLevel, c.CPCID, c.ParentID, c.Code, c.PT, c.EN, c.ES, c.IT, Level + 1, Cast(ac.Nodes + '->' + c.Code as varchar(max))");
        cmdText.Append("    FROM Categorias c ");
        cmdText.Append("   INNER JOIN ArvoreCategorias ac ON c.ParentID = ac.CPCID");
        cmdText.Append(")");
        cmdText.Append("SELECT * FROM ArvoreCategorias ORDER BY Nodes");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = Conn;
        cmd.CommandText = cmdText.ToString();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        List<Categoria> ArvoreCategorias = new List<Categoria>();

        //Loope perlo retorno da CTE
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Categoria cat = new Categoria();
            cat.NumLevel = Int32.Parse(dr["NumLevel"].ToString());
            cat.CPCID = Int32.Parse(dr["CPCID"].ToString());
            cat.ParentID = Int32.Parse(dr["ParentID"].ToString());
            cat.Code = dr["Code"].ToString();
            cat.Nodes = dr["Nodes"].ToString();
            cat.EN = dr["EN"].ToString();
            cat.ES = dr["ES"].ToString();
            cat.PT = dr["PT"].ToString();
            cat.IT = dr["IT"].ToString();

            ArvoreCategorias.Add(cat);
        }

        //Separo as Categorias Pai para que sejam preenchidos os filhos
        List<Categoria> ArvoreCategoriasPai = ArvoreCategorias.Where(c => c.ParentID == 0).ToList();

        //Carregos os Filhos das Categorias Raízes
        foreach (Categoria cat in ArvoreCategoriasPai)
        {
            CarregarCategoriasFilho(cat, ArvoreCategorias);
        }

        dr.Close();
        dr.Dispose();

        DAL.Conexao.FechaConexao(Conn);

        foreach (Categoria Cat in ArvoreCategoriasPai)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Cat.Nodes);

            if (Cat.CategoriasFilho.Count > 0)
            {
                EscreverCategoriasFilho(Cat);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

O Método recursivo para Preenchimento dos objetos filhos

```
    private static void CarregarCategoriasFilho(Categoria CategoriaPai, List<Categoria> ArvoreCategorias)
    {
        List<Categoria> CategoriasFilho = ArvoreCategorias.Where(cf => cf.ParentID == CategoriaPai.CPCID).ToList();
        CategoriaPai.CategoriasFilho = CategoriasFilho;

        if (CategoriasFilho.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Categoria cf in CategoriasFilho)
            {
                CarregarCategoriasFilho(cf, ArvoreCategorias);
            }
        }
    }
```

O Método recursivo para Escrever a saída do Node da Categoria

```
    private static void EscreverCategoriasFilho(Categoria Cat)
    {
        foreach (Categoria cf in Cat.CategoriasFilho)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cf.Nodes);

            if (cf.CategoriasFilho.Count > 0)
            {
                EscreverCategoriasFilho(cf);
            }
        }
    }
```